# Post custom media from Facebook App Canvas to user Feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-canvas

I am developing an Facebook Game App and I'd like to reward users to post custom media content (such as images and videos) from the Facebook app canvas to their own feeds. I just can't see Facebook supporting this based on their API Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to reward users for posting/liking/sharing etc...
Please read Facebook policy: https://developers.facebook.com/policy